# Thousands of IP Addresses/Interfaces vs. slow program performance

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a CentOS 5.9 machine set up with 5000+ IP addresses (secondary) for eth2.
My program only uses 2 for 2 UDP sockets (1 RX, 1 TX).
When I run the application, the CPU usage is almost 100% all the time.
When I drop down the number of the IP addresses (10), everything go to the normal - hardly 1% CPU usage.

Program is basically a client - server application. It uses non blocking r/w and epoll_wait()
for event waiting.

Can someone please explain to me why so high CPU usage for binary that only use small portion
of configured addresses.

Comment: Maybe because it's not designed to be efficient when configured with a ridculous number of IP addresses? But this question probably belongs on ServerFault, not StasckOverflow...

Comment: Without any code it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Roddy's statement might be valid, may be CentOs was not designed to handle these high number of address requests. Did you try with any there Linux flavors like RedHat, Ubuntu server editions for your setup?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think  the question posted talks about number of sockets but rather number of addresses on the interface. Although it seems a little strange as to why your program goes too high in CPU with this number, but in general number of addresses will affect the performance of the IP stack to deal with incoming packets and outgoing packets. Like when you call a send, and your socket is not bound, kernel needs to determine an IP address to put in the packet based on the destination address, and if that takes time it will show up in your process context.

But these still does not explain much, I guess putting a gprof will be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Handling thousands of sockets takes specialized software. Most network programmers naively use "select" and expect that to scale up to thousands of sockets well... which it definitely does not. A more event-driven model scales much better ... the event being a new socket or data on the socket, etc.

For Linux and Windows I use Libevent. It's a socket wrapper and not very hard to use and it scales nicely to ten-of-thousands of sockets.

```
http://libevent.org/
```

Look at the website here and you can see the logarithmic graph that shows tens of thousands of sockets performing as though they were 100. Of course, if the sockets are super busy, then you are right back to low-performance, but most sockets in the world are mostly quiet and this is where libevent shines. There are other libraries as well like ZeroMq (C# mono), libev, Boost.ASIO.

```
http://zeromq.org/
http://libev.schmorp.de/bench.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html
```

Here is my working, super-simple sample. You'll need to add threading protections but with less than an hour's work, you could easily support a few thousand simultaneous connections.

```
http://pastebin.com/g02S2RTi
```

Comment: The OP hasn't said one word about 'handling thousands of sockets'. On the contrary, he has explicitly mentioned *two* sockets, and thousands of *addresses.* Clearly you haven't actually read the question. -1